# Secure the web site according to the roles?

Tags: asp.net, authorization, informix, elmah, asp.net-roles

I use `ELMAH` locally and I wanna to use it in the production environment.  When I search, I found the following:

> Recall that in the ELMAH configuration's  section we set the
>   allowRemoteAccess attribute to 0, which prohibits remote users from
>   viewing the error log. It's important to prohibit anonymous visitors
>   from viewing the error log, as the error details might reveal security
>   vulnerabilities or other sensitive information. If you decide to set
>   this attribute to 1 and enable remote access to the error log then it
>   is important to lock down the elmah.axd path so that only authorized
>   visitors can access it. This can be achieved by adding a 
>   element to the Web.config file.

I wanna enable `remote access`, so according to the same article, I should do the following:

```
 <location path="elmah.axd">
  <system.web>
  <authorization>
  <allow roles="Admin" />
  <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
  </system.web>  
  </location>
```

My question is:

- I use Informix database, so how to handle the role idea when logging in, according to Informix?
- And if I wanna to store the log data should I use `sql server` or `mysql`
  data base, because I didn't find the `informix` database required in
  `ELMAH` downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use informix database, so how to handle the role idea when
>   logining,according to the informix?

You will have to write a custom Role Provider that use your `Informix` database. You can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx)

> And if i wanna to store the log data should i use sql server or mysql
>   data base, because i didn't find the informix database required in
>   ELMAH downloads?

You can use `XmlErrorLog`. Which saves logs as XML files.